# How can I call a custom function using a library?

Tags: node.js

I am trying to call a custom function based on [this documentation](https://docs.thegzm.space/PaginationEmbed.html#addFunctionEmoji):

```
.addFunctionEmoji(":regional_indicator_v:", deleteUser())
...
Function deleteUser() {
    console.log(“works”)
}
```

I get the following error message:

> Failed to send message
>   TypeError: Callback for :regional_indicator_v: must be a function type.

How can I call my function here?

Answer (score 0):

[addFunctionEmoji](https://docs.thegzm.space/PaginationEmbed.html#addFunctionEmoji) expects a function as the second parameter.

In order to invoke `deleteUser`, the best thing is to wrap it in a function:

```
.addFunctionEmoji(":regional_indicator_v:",() => deleteUser())
```